# Do you always have to start at the index zero when writing a 2D list?

Tags: c#, list, 2d, 4d

I want to fill in a 2Dlist, but start at the third position [2]. Is this somehow possible?
A short code for understanding what i mean:

```
List<List<string>> List2D = new List<List<string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  List2D[2].Add("i")
}
```

I get the following error:
`Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index`

EDIT: Any idea how to fill in a 4D list?

```
List<List<List<List<string>>>> List4D = new List<List<List<List<string>>>>();

for (int i = 0; i < List1.Count; i++)
{
    List<List<List<string>>> List3D = new List<List<List<string>>>();
    for (int j = 0; j < List2.Count; j++)
    {
        List<List<string>> List2D = new List<List<string>>();
        for (int k = 0; k < List3.Count; k++)
        {
            List<string> Lijst1D = new List<string>();
            List2D.Add(Lijst1D);
        }
        List3D.Add(List2D);
    }
    List4D.Add(List3D);
}
```

So later I can call: `List4D[2][3][0].Add("test");`

Comment: What is the problem with your approach? Apart from the fact that it doesn't compile due to your typos.

Comment: `List2D[2]` is the third `List<string>` in your `List2D`. It does not have any `List<string>`  at start.

Comment: it tells me `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index`

Comment: This means your List2D is having less that 3 elements.

Comment: You can wrap `List<List<string>>` into *your own class* and thus provide the possibility

Comment: `new List<List<string>>();` this will create an empty `List<List<string>>`, so it will have Count = 0

Comment: I didnt add anything to the List2D yet, is this why?

Comment: You can start at a later position but you have to add the first two lists as null reference(or empty list), otherwise you can't access the third list.

Comment: Okay i totally understand it now, thank you. after looking back to my question, it was a stupid question

Comment: First, it's a 2D list so you need two parameters for choosing the index; like: `List2D[2][2]`. Second, I think you looking for something else rather than index, the index is the ordered number of items in the list so it should start at zero; a little more explanation should be nice

Comment: I edited my question to a 4D list, but this isnt working, i cannot call `List4D[2][3][0].Add("test");` , anyone got anyu idea why this isnt working?

Answer (score 1):

Since you just created your `List2D` and not added any nested list into it, you can't access its third element (there is nothing there).

You have to add some items first:

```
List<List<string>> List2D = new List<List<string>>();
List2D.Add(new List<string>());
List2D.Add(new List<string>());
List2D.Add(new List<string>());

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
  List2D[2].Add("i")
}
```

**Update**

Well, core idea of filling that list remains the same: if you want to access `List4D[2][3][0]` - first you need  to fill all of lists in "path".

You can do it something like this:

```
List<List<List<List<string>>>> List4D = new List<List<List<List<string>>>>();

int i1 = 2, i2 = 3, i3 = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= Math.Max(i1, 1); i++)
    List4D.Add(new List<List<List<string>>>());

for (int i = 0; i <= Math.Max(i2, 1); i++)
    List4D[i1].Add(new List<List<string>>());

for (int i = 0; i <= Math.Max(i3, 1); i++)
    List4D[i1][i2].Add(new List<string>());

List4D[i1][i2][i3].Add("test");
```

Frankly, idea of 4D list looks a little bit "syntetic". In real application probably it is not the best data structure because of clumsy addressing.

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping me out. Could you have me with the edit i made in my question, its about a 4D list